# Display username with cookies

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have created a connection between php and mysql ,and i added a username and password on mysql table so i can login and redirect to a "members" page. It works at this point but what i want to do is to display "username" in some places in my "members" page with cookies.

On first.php , on navbar, blockquote where it says "User" thats where i want to replace it with the username that logins but with cookies and i haven't understood how to do it

My files:

config.php

```
<?php
    $mysql_hostname="localhost";
    $mysql_user="root";
    $mysql_password="root";
    $mysql_database="Electricians";

    $bd=mysql_connect($mysql_hostname,$mysql_user,$mysql_password)or   die("Bad Connection");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_database,$bd)or die("Bad Connection");
    ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    header("location:login.php");
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("includes/config.php");

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{

    $myusername=addslashes($_POST ['username']);
    $mypassword=md5(addslashes($_POST[ 'password']));



$sql="SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1)
{

    $_SESSION['login_admin']=$myusername;

    header("location:http://localhost:8888/offlineproject/first.php");

}
}   
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">                 
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/csc" href="css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/csc" href="css/login.css">
  <title>Online Drawing for Electricians</title>
 </head>                 
 <body>             
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>       
                </button>              
            </div>

             <div class="navbar-header">
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logoattop" src="images/nklogo.png" alt="Logo" >Online Drawing for Electricians </a>
      </div>


        </div>
      </nav><
      <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>Online Drawing for Electricians</h1>
                <div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" method="post">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input name="username" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
             </div>
           <a href="first.php">Skip</a>
        </div>
        </div>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>                 
</html>
```

first.php

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">                 
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/theme.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
     <link href="css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Online Drawing for Electricians</title>
 </head>                 
 <body>             
     <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>   
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>       
                </button>              
            </div>
            <!navbar header-->
             <div class="navbar-header">
                 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logoattop" src="images/nklogo.png" alt="Logo" >Online Drawing for Electricians </a>
      </div>
               <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href=#><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> <User></a></li>
        <li><a href="/offlineproject/logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
            </div>

        </div><!End-Container-->
      </nav><!End-Nav-Bar-->
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container text-center">
          <h1>Online Drawing for Electricians</h1>
          <div class="btn-group">
                        <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning ">Search</a>
              <a href="" class="btn btn-lg btn-default ">Upload</a>

          </div>
          </div>
      </div> <!End Jumbotron-->
    <!Blockquotes-->
      <div class="container">
      <section>
          <div class= "page-header" id="feedback">
          <h2>Recent activity of <small><User></small></h2>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
              <blockquote>
              <p>"User" Today job is to fix the cables of the central bank.</p>
              <p>Cables need to be fixed as soon as possible </p>
              <footer>NK Electrical LTD</footer>
              </blockquote>
          </div>
           <div class="col-lg-12">
              <blockquote>
              <p>Something Something 
              SomethingSomething
              SomethingSomethingSomething</p>
              <footer>Aris Con</footer>
              </blockquote>
          </div>
          </div>
          </section>
          <a href="planedit.php">Skip</a>
              </div>




<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>                 
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(session_destroy())
    {
        header("location: index.php");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: You're using old and insecure functions, such as MD5 for instance and not sanitizing anything. I hope this is for educational purposes and not intended to go live. This is totally insecure.

Comment: To answer this; just use sessions in there too, pull in the session array and echo it; *done like dinner*. You don't need to use cookies for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a user/pass is set, you can't presume they are an admin, unless there is some further checking done. Either via a flag in the database or by matching a hardcoded value somewhere.

So you need to change this up to something like this:

```
$sql="SELECT userid FROM users WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if($row['is_admin'] == '1'){

    $_SESSION['login_admin']=$myusername;

    header("location:http://localhost:8888/offlineproject/first.php");
    exit;
}
else{
      // do something else here
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for set cookie

```
$first_name = 'Rilakkuma';  

setcookie('first_name',$first_name,time() + (86400 * 7)); // 86400 = 1 day
```

And for call cookie

```
$_COOKIE['first_name'];
```

See more here --> http://davidwalsh.name/php-cookies

Answer (score 0):

$first_name = "user";

then setcookie(); use this one for setting cookie

$COOKIE['first_name']